# Large Qt Sqlite SELECT Statement

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a database with a table containing ~150 million rows. The columns are just:

`id (INTEGER), value_one (INTEGER), value_two (INTEGER), value_3 (INTEGER)`

I'm need to import all this data into a `QList`, but I'm running into a problem where Qt is asserting `qAllocMore: 'Requested size is too large!', file tools\qbytearray.cpp, line 73` when I'm running a `SELECT` query. I'm able to run the same code on a table containing ~7 million entries, and it works without error.

This is my `SELECT` statement:

```
 bool e = query.exec("SELECT * FROM DocumentTerms");
 if (!e) {
     qWarning() << __FUNCTION__ << "\tError: " << query.lastError().text();
 }
 while (query.next()) {
     int docId = query.value(1).toInt();
     int termId = query.value(2).toInt();
     int frequency = query.value(3).toInt();
     //store it in a QHash<int, QPair<int, int>>
 }
```

It looks like it's iterating through the `query.next` loop, but the assert pops up after ~16 million iterations. Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: Looks like you're running out of memory, are you on 32bit OS? and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: 64 bit machine and a 64 bit executable. I'm running with 8 gigs of RAM. I'm using another 8 gigs with a paging file. I'm running on Windows 7.

Comment: I don't know if you are trying to display this data in some sort of U/I, but if so, then I would say this is a design flaw.  You should be using some sort of paging mechanism instead.

Comment: No, I'm using this as part of a semantic analysis engine. It involves a large set of training data.

Comment: I deleted my post. It contained a very stupid calculation bug. Too late for stuff like that here. :-) I tried a QHash<int, QPair<int, int>> with 150000000 entries. No problem for my machine.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was nonsense. Stupid calculation bug. However, I think I now have the solution. It is not memory in general, what you are missing, but consecutive memory.

I have tried the following:

```
QList<int> testlist;
for(int i = 0; i < 150000000;++i){
    testlist << i << i << i << i;
}
```

Stupid little code, does nothing else, but put 4 ints 150000000 times into a list.
I get after a few seconds:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc

More or less: Out of memory.

Now I change the code above:

```
QList<int> testlist;
testList.reserve(150000000*4);
for(int i = 0; i < 150000000;++i){
    testlist << i << i << i << i;
}
```

This code does nothing else than the one before. The QList is exactly the same size as before. However, I reserve all memory before I start the loop. The result? The list does not need to grow and constantly request more memory. With this version I had no problem at all. I got my list.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give it a shot :)